# permissions changed from 14.04 to 16.04?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade, permissions

in my home directory I have a procedure running rdiff-backup, 
I run this procedure with root-rights as a cron.

The output-log-file I create with touch within this procedure.

Before this procedure ends I do a `sudo chown <me>:<me> /home/<me>/<log-file>`.

In 14.04 I could open this log-file normally but in 16.04.1 I need to enter the Password.

Why did the behavior change?

here the ls-l inside the procedure:

```
#touch $LogDatei;
#ls -l $LogDatei;
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Sep 23 11:41 /home/khg/Sicherungen/logs/2016-09/2016-09-23-11-41-02-reorg.log

#rdiff-backup --remove-older-than 10Y /media/KHG0001TB/  &>> $LogDatei;
#ls -l $LogDatei;
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 66 Sep 23 11:41 /home/khg/Sicherungen/logs/2016-09/2016-09-23-11-41-02-reorg.log

#chown khg:users $LogDatei;
#touch $LogDatei
#ls -l $LogDatei;
-rw-r--r-- 1 khg users 66 Sep 23 11:41 /home/khg/Sicherungen/logs/2016-09/2016-09-23-11-41-02-reorg.log
```

while inserting the `ls -l` lines into the script I noticed, I also could open this file only with password.  so this seems to be a general problem.

```
#getfacl /home/khg/Sicherungen/logs/2016-09/2016-09-23-11-41-02-reorg.log -e
# file: home/khg/Sicherungen/logs/2016-09/2016-09-23-11-41-02-reorg.log
# owner: khg
# group: users
user::rw-
group::r--
other::r--
```

Comment: Can you show the output of `ls -l [your-log-file]` before the root process has updated the file and the output of `ls` after the root process has updated it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While updating from 14.04 to 16.04 the order of the applications for text *.log  was changed. I had an entry for 'kate' named Kate and one for 'kdesudo kate' named KateP.

In the old order 'kate' came first. After update 'kdesudo kate' was first.

So this was the reason.